# Counter example to this claim about monotone sequences converging to $0$ which aren't summable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\{\gamma_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers, i.e. $\gamma_k\geq 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, which is not summable, i.e. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_k=\infty$. Furthermore, we assume that $\gamma_k \geq \gamma_{k+1}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $\gamma_k\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. What is a sequence which satisfies the above but $\sup\limits_k \frac{\gamma_k}{\gamma_{k+1}}=\infty$?

My own attempt did not get far. I define $\gamma_k$ in the following way,
\begin{align}
\gamma_k = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k} & k\leq \eta_0\\
\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{10^{n^2}}\right) & \eta_{n-1}< k \leq \eta_{n}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

and then i try to pick the sequence $\eta_k$ in such a way that $\gamma_k$ is not summable. We also have for $k=\eta_n$,

$$\frac{\gamma_k}{\gamma_{k+1}} = \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right) \frac{10^{(n+1)^2}}{10^{n^2}}=\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)10^{2n+1}$$

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that the ratio is approximately always the same, $100$. You need boundlessly increasing ratios.

Comment: Yes, I edited it to reflect that. Now the ratios approach infinity as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: How is that? Except for the small contribution from $(k+1)/k$, which goes to $1$ for $k\to\infty$, you only have ratios of $100$ at the places where $n$ increases by $1$. Or were you thinking of letting $n$ increase by more than $1$ at a time?

Comment: Sorry; it was a mistake even with the edit, you're correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In the $n$-th step, let $\gamma$ drop by a factor of $10^n$, and then append $10^{n(n+1)/2}$ constant elements before the next drop. Each such stretch of constant elements contributes the same amount to the sum, which therefore diverges, yet there are arbitrarily high ratios $10^n$.

Comment: This is basically what I was trying myself, except I am not sure what is meant by "$n$-th step". Maybe you can be more explicit in the construction?

Comment: @TonyS.F.: I meant that you construct the sequence step by step. For instance, start off with $\gamma_1=1$, then append $10^1$ copies of $10^{-1}$, then $10^3$ copies of $10^{-3}$, then $10^6$ copies of $10^{-6}$, and so on.